# Cross compiling for ARM, float32x4_t cannot be resolved

Tags: c, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, neon

I'm trying to cross comple a bunch of C files from `SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 i686 GNU/Linux` to `ARM Coretex-A9` platform. `Linaro linaro-alip 3.0.35-02828-g5cedf96` is running on the ARM board.

**Problems**

1. `<arm_neon.h>` is missing.
2. NEON data types like `float32x4_t`, `uint32x4_t`, `float32x4x2_t` throws error *Type float32x4x2_t could not be resolved*.

**My attempts**

1. I manually [downloaded](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5664/gcc/config/arm/arm_neon.h) `<arm_neon.h>` and placed in the same directory as my C files. Also made sure that the compiler options `-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon` are present in the cross compiler toolchain. Now the header file issue is solved.
2. Still the second issue persist.

Some of the referred fixes: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228855/header-files-for-simd-intrinsics/22291538#22291538), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490034/how-do-i-use-arm-neon-intrinsics).

Could anyone pass some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the cross-compiler doesn't provide arm_neon.h itself, I'd take that as a hint it doesn't support NEON intrinsics. What are the details of the cross-compiler you're trying to use (version, configuration, etc.)?

Comment: Cross compiler: `gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.09_linux`, prefix `arm-linux-gnueabihf-`.

Comment: If you're using NEON you should be using `-mfloat-abi=hard` not `softfp` surely?. I checked `gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.10` on windows and it does have `arm_neon.h`

Comment: Odd. The closest Linaro toolchain I have to hand is [the 13.08 release](https://releases.linaro.org/13.08/components/toolchain/binaries/), and that has arm_neon.h as expected. Also those typedefs are right there in the very same file. It would help to see [a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code and compiler settings that can reproduce this.

Comment: [SOLVED]: @BrianSidebotham You were right (+1) . I was mislead by the preamble in `arm_neon.h` file, that says *You must enable NEON instructions...* @Notikethat: Thanks for your time and inputs that steer to the right direction(+1). [Related Q&A can be found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753749/arm-compilation-error-vpf-registered-used-by-executable-not-object-file)