# Why can't I change gcc compiler from 4.2.1 to later version?

Tags: macos, gcc

I've tried to replace the included gcc 4.2.1 compiler on my Mac Book Pro with latest version of Mac OSX but can't figure out what Im doing wrong:

Also this screen scrape from my shell doesn't make sense for me:

Johans-MBP:bin johanlindfors$ **gcc --version**
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
Johans-MBP:bin johanlindfors$ **which gcc**
/usr/local/bin/gcc
Johans-MBP:bin johanlindfors$ **/usr/local/bin/gcc --version**
gcc (Homebrew GCC 8.2.0) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Johans-MBP:bin johanlindfors$

Comment: Try running `type gcc` to see if you have an alias or function defined.

Comment: Try also `hash -r` to make your shell rehash its tables.

Comment: The system gcc-4.2.1 compiler is a legacy of the change over to clang. I should never be used for your own code. Edit your `.profile` or `.tcshrc` to prepend the newer gcc directory to the path. Or save a lot of time and energy and use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org).

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's actually Apple Clang pretending to be GCC.

Answer (score 1):

The system gcc-4.2.1 compiler is a (very old) legacy of the migration from the gcc to clang compilers. It should never be used for your own code. Edit your `.profile` or `.tcshrc` to prepend the newer gcc directory to the path. Or save a lot of time and energy and use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).

Unfortunately, Clang has established 'absolute' compatibility at gcc-4.2.1: see: `clang -E -dM - < /dev/null | grep GNU`

That's not a bad thing. Once the compiler gains traction it's going to provide it's own extensions, and no longer track those of others. Many extensions remain compatible like Intel's `<x86intrin.h>`. It's not really in either compiler's interests to provide too much divergence with extensions...

The 'stable' gcc is now `8.2.0` according to MacPorts. The stable MacPorts clang (which irritably conflicts with OS X) is apparently `7.0.0` ... short story - don't go replacing sets of files arbitrarily that you think *might* work. Then set up paths correctly - IIRC, MacPorts will do this for you.

I provided a more recent summary: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228855/header-files-for-x86-simd-intrinsics/42493893#42493893).