# Including the correct intrinsic header

Tags: c, gcc, header, intel, intrinsics

I keep reading opinions on which header file is better to include to access Intel's intrinsics : `x86intrin.h` or `immintrin.h` .

Both seem to achieve an identical outcome, but I'm sure there must some subtle differences, with regards to code portability. Maybe one is more common, or more complete, than the other ?

I couldn't find an explanation on any of them. If anyone knows why there are 2 files, and what differences they have, this would be a welcomed SO answer.

Speaking of portability, for older compilers (like `gcc` < v4.4.0), of course things become more complex, and neither is available. One has to consider including *another* intrinsic header (likely `emmintrin.h` for SSE support).

Comment: I just include the specific ones for the intrinsics I'm using. Intel's reference guide includes (hah!) them in the notes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(posting an answer here because [Header files for x86 SIMD intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228855/header-files-for-x86-simd-intrinsics) has out of date answers that suggest including individual header files).

---

**`immintrin.h` is portable across all compilers, and includes all *Intel* SIMD intrinsics**, and some scalar extensions like `_pdep_u32` that are available with `-mbmi2` or a `-march=` that includes it.  (For AMD SSE4a and XOP (Bulldozer-family only, dropped for Zen), you need to include a different header as well.)

The only reason I can think of for including `<emmintrin.h>` specifically would be if you're using MSVC and want to leave intrinsics undefined for ISA extensions you don't want to depend on.

GCC's model of requiring you to enable extensions before you can use intrinsics for them means the compiler does this checking for you, so you can just `#include <immintrin.h>` but still get an error if you try to use `_mm_shuffle_epi8` (`pshufb`) without `-mssse3`.

**Don't use compilers older than gcc4.4.**  They're obsolete and will typically generate slower code, especially for modern CPUs that didn't exist when their tuning settings were being decided.

---

gcc/clang's `x86intrin.h` vs. MSVC `intrin.h` are only useful if you need some extra non-SIMD intrinsics like MSVC's `_BitScanReverse()` that aren't always portable across compilers.  Stuff like integer rotate / bit-scan intrinsics that are baseline (unlike BMI1 `lzcnt`/`tzcnt` or BMI2 `rorx`) but hard or impossible to express in C in a way that compilers will recognize and turn a loop back into a single instruction.

Intel documents some of those as being available in immintrin.h in [their intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=bsf), but gcc/clang and MSVC actually have them in their `x86intrin.h` or `intrin.h` headers, respectively.

See [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/get-cpu-cycle-count/51907627#51907627) for an example of **using `#ifdef _MSC_VER` to choose the right header** to define `uint64_t __rdtsc(void)` and `__rdtscp()`.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, that's excellent stuff, accurate and complete.