# Gcc doesn't recognize an intel instrinsic

Tags: c++, gcc, intel

I'm trying to use the Intel intrinsic gcc builtin-function `_pext_u64`. Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << _pext_u64(25, 56) << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Compilation line and error:

```
$ make
g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp  -O3 -mbmi2
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:18: error: '_pext_u64' was not declared in this scope
    5 |     std::cout << _pext_u64(25, 56) << '\n';
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~
```

Additional info:

```
$ gcc -dumpmachine
x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

What is going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Header files for x86 SIMD intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228855/header-files-for-x86-simd-intrinsics) and also `-mbmi2` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/qEx44z4dd

Comment: The intel intrinsics are not compiler builtins. They are declared as functions in a header.