# Find if a number is a power of two without math function or log function

Tags: java

I want to find if a user entered number is a power of two or not.

My code doesn't work.

```
public class power_of_two
{  
    public static void main(String args[])  
    {  

        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number : ");
        int num = in.nextInt();

        int other = 1;  
        if(((~num) & 1) == 1)  
        {  
            System.out.println("The number is a power of two");  
        }  
        else  
        {
            System.out.println("The number is a  NOT A power of two");  
        }
    }  
}
```

Let me know how can I find the power of two number.
For example 8 is a power of 2.
22 is **not** a power of 2, etc..

Comment: Your code checks for multiples of 2, not power of 2.

Comment: I don't think this question was rightfully closed. The linked "duplicate questions" are about two different languages (C# and PHP, respectively). Sure, the semantics are the same, but this is specifically a *Java* question. For reference, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189850/how-should-duplicates-of-language-independent-questions-be-handled.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You can test if a positive integer `n` is a power of 2 with something like

```
(n & (n - 1)) == 0
```

If `n` can be non-positive (i.e. negative or zero) you should use

```
(n > 0) && ((n & (n - 1)) == 0)
```

---

If `n` is truly a power of 2, then in binary it will look like:

```
10000000...
```

so `n - 1` looks like

```
01111111...
```

and when we [bitwise-AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) them:

```
  10000000...
& 01111111...
  -----------
  00000000...
```

Now, if `n` *isn't* a power of 2, then its binary representation will have some other 1s in addition to the leading 1, which means that both `n` and `n - 1` will have the same leading 1 bit (since subtracting 1 cannot possibly turn off this bit if there is another 1 in the binary representation somewhere). Hence the `&` operation cannot produce `0` if `n` is not a power of 2, since `&`ing the two leading bits of `n` and `n - 1` will produce `1` in and of itself. This of course assumes that `n` is positive.

This is also explained in ["Fast algorithm to check if a positive number is a power of two"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two#Fast_algorithm_to_check_if_a_positive_number_is_a_power_of_two) on Wikipedia.

---

Quick sanity check:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if ((i & (i - 1)) == 0)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
```

Comment: `( n & (n - 1) == 0 ) && n > 0`

Comment: @lining `-16` is not a power of 2.

Comment: I recently found out about this alternative approach, which works based on the same principle and is a lot more modular(?): `Integer.bitCount(n) == 1`

Answer (score 97):

You can use the [`bitwise AND (&) operator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html):

```
return (num & -num) == num
```

**Why this works?**

Consider the number 8, what it is in binary (assuming 32-bits)?

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000
```

Now let's see how -8 is represented? [<sup>1</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000
```

Finally.. let's calculate `8 & -8`:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000   8
↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓   &
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000  -8
---------------------------------------
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000   8    ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

Now let's take another example, let's say `7`, which is **not** power of two.

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111   7
↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓   &                       
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1001  -7
---------------------------------------
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001  != 7  ¯\_(ة_ة)_/¯
```

As mentioned by @arshajii, think what will happen if `num` is zero.. I'll leave the solution for you :)

<sup>1</sup> A good way to remember how to calculate that: Begin from the rightmost bit, for each 0 you see, don't change it, when you see 1, leave it and proceed, but from now on, invert all bits. I tried to explain this more [here](http://marounbassam.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/bitwise-operations-find-if-number-is_6.html).

Comment: May not be obvious as to why that is -8. Perhaps where that came from (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) would be helpful.

Comment: I think you need a `num != 0 && ...` in there (if `num` can be `0`). Otherwise +1

Comment: If the `num` < 0 e.g. -8 then this would fail.  I guess you need to check that it is the absolute value of num, but +1 anyway

Comment: Why `if (cond) { return true; }` instead of  `return cond;` ?

Comment: The check against zero can be done like `(num & - num) > (num - 1)`

Comment: @TemplateRex that will return `true` for 0, which is *not* a power of 2.

Comment: at least in C++ [it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/116119eb5337ce78), did you try this in Java?

Answer (score 7):

```
double input = 22;

while(((input != 2) && input % 2 == 0) || input == 1) {
 input = input /2;
}

return input == 2;
```

Keep dividing it by 2 until you reach 1 or an odd number. If it reaches 1 it's a power of 2, otherwise it isn't.

Comment: I agree. If the OP is looking for readability this is the approach he should take, but performance wise the other algorithms are much better.

Comment: Don't forget to re assign `input`.. For now this loop is infinite.

Comment: Not the fastest solution, but one that needs less knowledge of 2-er complements and bit hacking. Like Bubblesort for sorting which is a bad solution but one easy to understand

Comment: Not only is this less readable but the title of the question says "without math function" which I would assume means not using the division operator.

Comment: @Eterm: the way I interpreted the question was that he couldn't use `Math` functions, otherwise he would've specified that it would be bitwise.

Comment: This code doesn't work for `input=1`. Maybe you should replace `input/2` by `input` in all conditions. In addition, it might be good to avoid an infinite loop for `input=0`.

Comment: Also, does the `%` operator work with `double` type? (I am not familiar with Java)

Comment: why would this not work for `input=1`? the first condition so there is no loop and it will return false (as it should). I agree though that `input=0` will loop infinitely

Comment: @JeroenVannevel 1 is a power of 2, it is 2^0.

Answer (score 5):

The straightforward solution:

```
bool isPowerOfTwo(int n) {
    // All values < 1 cannot be (positive, at least) powers of two.
    if (n < 1) return false;

    // Keep shifting bits.
    while (n > 1) {
        // Since n > 1, the low bit set means at least two bits must
        // be set, making n no longer a power of two.
        if (n & 0x1) return false;
        // Throw away the bottom (zero) bit.
        n >>= 1;
    }
    // Only one bit was set, therefore, n is a power of two.
    return true;
}
```

Of course, this is not as optimal as some of the other bit-trickery solutions (which are indeed quite clever), but it's very easy to see how it works, and verify it works in your head.

For the input `4`, we get:

```
n = 4 (0x100)
run loop
n = 2 (0x10)
run loop
n = 1 (0x1)
return true
```

For an invalid input, like `5`, we get:

```
n = 5 (0x101)
return false (0x101 & 0x1 => 0x1, which is truthy)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public boolean isPowerOfTwo(int n){

            boolean isPower=false;
            int temp=n;

            while(temp>=2){
                if(temp%2==0){
                    isPower=true;

                }else{
                    isPower=false;
                    break;
                }
                temp=temp/2;
            }

            if(isPower){
                System.out.println("power of 2");
            }else{
                System.out.println("not power of 2");
            }

            return isPower;
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

A very simple solution.

```
int n = 8; // any integer and you can take it from user also
for(;n>0;n++){
    if(n%2 != 0) {
        System.out.println("not a power of two")
        return;
    } // if ends here
    n = n/2;
}// for ends here
System.out.println("power of two")
```

Comment: You can't do `n++` in this case and the expression must be `n >=2 `.