# Java: Finding if number is power of 2

Tags: java

Found the solution as:

```
private static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int number) {
        if(number <=0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(number + " is too small.");
        }
        if ((number & -number) == number) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But could not understand one of the if statement. 
What is the meaning of `if ((number & -number) == number)` here?

Comment: Look up the `&` operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find if a number is a power of two without math function or log function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383248/find-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-two-without-math-function-or-log-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The & is a bitwise AND operator. You need to know a bit of binary numbers to know how that function works.

Negative numbers are represented using the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) notation, where the leftmost bit is used to indicate whether the number is positive (if 0) or negative (if 1).

A number is a power of 2 if it is represented by a sequence of binary digits, whose value is 0 for all but one. For instance, 2^6 = 64 is represented by 0100 0000

The corresponding negative number is calculated by applying a bitwise NOT operator (i.e. changing all 0 to 1 and all 1 to 0), then adding 1 to the result - in our example:

```
0100 0000 becomes 1011 1111 + 1 = 1100 0000
```

If you line up the 2 binary numbers:

```
0100 0000
1100 0000
```

and apply the bitwise AND, the resulting number is the original number 64:

```
0100 0000
```

That explains why `number & -number == number` is used to determine whether a number is a power of 2.
To prove that, let's try with a couple other numbers not power of 2:

```
0100 0001 (65)
1011 1111 (-65)
---------
0000 0001 (1)

0000 0011 (3)
1111 1101 (-3)
---------
0000 0001 (1)
```