# Calculating log to the base 2 in java gives inaccurate results

Tags: java, math, logarithm, natural-logarithm

Consider this program to determine if a given number is a power of 2.

```
class Solution{
    
    // Function to check if given number n is a power of two.
    public static boolean isPowerofTwo(long n){
        
        // Your code here
        float x = (float)Math.log(n)/(float)Math.log(2);
        System.out.println(x);
        if(x%1==0)
           return true;
        return false;
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Then consider n =1073741824, while the output should be 30,it gives 29.999998.

Comment: This is as expected. Possily worse when you use `float` then if you used `double`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Using floating point math to test if a power of 2 is a bad idea

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2) I know it’s a C# question, but most answers should work in Java too. Or look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026924/java-finding-if-number-is-power-of-2).

Comment: or `Long.bitCount(n) == 1` (for strictly positive numbers) || why casting to `float`?

Comment: @user16320675 Nice. So `n > 0 && Long.bitCount(n) == 1` will cover all cases. (In fact the only case where your code does not work correctly is the case where the single 1 is the sign bit.)

Comment: `n > 0` is actually only needed to *avoid* `n == Long.MIN_VALUE`  - the only non-positive value with exactly one bit set

Answer (score 0):

Don't use floating point math to determine if a number is a power of 2. Use this instead:

```
return n > 0 && (n&(n-1)) == 0;
```