# Unexpected Compilation Error in Java

Tags: java, segment-tree

This is a small code that if the length of input array is power of two then the size of segment array is 2*(input_array.length)-1 else 2*(next power of 2 after input_array.length)-1 .

```
public static int ByLogs(int n)
{
    double y = Math.floor(Math.log(n)/Math.log(2));
    return (int)Math.pow(2, y + 1);
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int input_array[] = {-1,2,4,0,3};

    if(( input_array.length & (input_array.length - 1) == 0 ) && input_array.length > 0)
        int [] segment_array = new int[2*(input_array.length)-1];
    else
        int [] segment_array = new int[2*(ByLogs(input_array.length))-1];

    //Arrays.fill(segment_array,999);

    System.out.println(segment_array.length);
}
```

but after compilation the following errors have been occurred.

```
SegmentTree.java:17: error: '.class' expected
        int [] segment_array = new int[2*(input_array.length)-1];
               ^
SegmentTree.java:17: error: not a statement
        int [] segment_array = new int[2*(input_array.length)-1];
            ^
SegmentTree.java:17: error: illegal start of expression
        int [] segment_array = new int[2*(input_array.length)-1];
                             ^
SegmentTree.java:17: error: ';' expected
        int [] segment_array = new int[2*(input_array.length)-1];
                              ^
SegmentTree.java:17: error: ']' expected
        int [] segment_array = new int[2*(input_array.length)-1];
                                       ^
SegmentTree.java:17: error: not a statement
        int [] segment_array = new int[2*(input_array.length)-1];
                                      ^
SegmentTree.java:17: error: illegal start of expression
        int [] segment_array = new int[2*(input_array.length)-1];
                                        ^
SegmentTree.java:17: error: ';' expected
        int [] segment_array = new int[2*(input_array.length)-1];
                                         ^
SegmentTree.java:17: error: not a statement
        int [] segment_array = new int[2*(input_array.length)-1];
                                                     ^
SegmentTree.java:17: error: ';' expected
        int [] segment_array = new int[2*(input_array.length)-1];
```

I couldn't find out my mistake.

Comment: Basically, the problem here, other than parenthesis is that you have initialized your array within the if statements, but that leaves in undeclared in the print statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the if statement.

See comment :

```
public static int ByLogs(int n)

{
    double y = Math.floor(Math.log(n)/Math.log(2));
    return (int)Math.pow(2, y + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int input_array[] = {-1,2,4,0,3};
    int [] segment_array;
    int n = input_array.length;

    //for positive n 
    if( (n & (n - 1)) == 0 ) {
        segment_array = new int[(2*(input_array.length))-1];
    } else {
        segment_array = new int[(2*(ByLogs(input_array.length)))-1];
    }

    //Arrays.fill(segment_array,999);

    System.out.println(segment_array.length);
}
```

Comment: But to check weather n is power of two we have check that if( n & n-1 == 0) or not i.e. we need to check bitwise AND.

Comment: `==` is the boolean operator, not the `&`

Comment: @c0der , my expression is algorithmic-ally correct, I can't change this because of compilation error. I need to know where the error has been occurred. Bitwise AND is the exact solution for chenck if a number is power of two or not

Comment: I Changed the if statement to check if n is a power of 2. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you can't actually declare a variable inside an if statement like that, since it goes out of [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Java) as soon as the block ends. So instead of:

```
if (...) {
  int[] a = ...;
} else {
  int[] a = ...;
}
```

you probably want:

```
int[] a; // declare the variable first, *then* initialize it
if (...) {
  a = ...;
} else {
  a = ...;
}
```

Second, your conditional is mangled; the left-hand side of the `&` is an `int` but the right-hand side is a `boolean`. The bitwise-and operator supports both types, but not together; to [convert a `boolean` to an `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3793650/113632) you can simply do so explicitly, e.g.

```
((input_array.length - 1) == 0) ? 1 : 0
```

To check whether [`input_array.length` is a power of two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19383248/113632) you want:

```
(input_array.length & (input_array.length - 1)) == 0
```

Notice the extra close-paren after `-1`.

Finally your syntax is sloppy, which is likely making your code harder to work with. Although Java allows array declarations in many forms (e.g. `int variable[]`, `int [] variable`, `int[] variable`) only the last one is in common usage. I would strongly suggest always declaring your arrays as `type[] variableName`, even though you don't have to. Similarly always use `{ }` when writing blocks (`if`, `else`, `for`, etc.) as it makes your code easier to read and safer to modify in the future.

Comment: Code runs fine with a space `int []`, by the way. Surprised you didn't point out `int input_array[]`, though, which is also correct

Comment: @cricket_007 oh weird, it wasn't compiling for me before but that clearly was one of the other issues manifesting itself strangely. Thanks, I'll fix my answer!

Comment: Yes I have found out the problem and thanks for helping me out. I have to first initialise the array then in the if-else statement I need to allocate the space. But could you explain why is it ?

Comment: @SoumyaKantiNaskar variables in Java are [scoped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) to the block containing them; in this case your `if` and `else` blocks. Once the block finishes the variable goes out of scope and can no longer be accessed. [This article](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html) provides some more background.