# Power of two failed to pass the test

Tags: java, algorithm

Isn't this one way to test whether a number is a power of 2?

```
boolean isPowerOfTwo(int n) {
        return (n%2==0);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the _witty humor_

Comment: why? i am serious.

Comment: This tells you if a number is divisible by 2, not a power of 2

Comment: You're checking if the number is even. This will say 6,12, 18,.... are power of 2.

Comment: do you think 40 is power of 2? when 40 can be divided by 2??

Comment: this is test if number is `even`. To test for power of 2, read this (or use google) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383248/find-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-two-without-math-function-or-log-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are checking power of 2? Rather, being checked divisible with 2. If you are serious, use the piece of cake snippet

```
return n > 0 && ((n & -n) == n);
```

The second way,

[image]

```
private static boolean powerOf2(int num)
{
  if(num <= 0){
   return false;
  }

  while(num > 1)
  {
   if(num % 2 != 0)
   {
    return false;
   }
   num = num / 2;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: let me come up with some other way,  i hate bit operation.

Comment: Note: this returns true for 0.

Answer (score 1):

That function checks whether or not an integer is even (i.e divisible by 2), not whether or not the integer is a power of 2.

To check if a number is a power of 2, you should look at its bits. `int`s that are a power of 2 will have one bit set to 1 and all others set to 0.

```
boolean isPowerOf2(int i) {
    return Integer.bitCount(i) == 1;
}
```

Comment: Tested, simple, yet inefficient. even worse than the recursive version.

Answer (score 0):

The % is the modulo operator, meaning the remainder after division. your method checks if the int n is divisible by 2

Comment: So my code is a necessary, but insufficient condition of being as a power of 2. right?

Comment: I would not put it in the "necessary" category, you are just checking if the number is dividable by 2 not if it is a power of 2. It is just doing something different. There is however a binary rule: if the binary version of your int only has one 1 digit, then it is a power of 2. This can be checked with a boolean operator n &   (n - 1) == 0

Comment: i mean it must be divisible by 2, which is necessary.

Comment: @ling Powers of 2 are actually a subset of even numbers - if you figure out that an integer is a power of 2, you don't need to check if the same integer is even.