# How to calculate the digit in the k position with a given pattern?

Tags: c++

Here's the problem: the inputs are 2 numbers n (n<=10^5) and k, and you need to find the digit of position k (k<=10^15) in a(n). the pattern here is a(n) = n+2*a(n-1) in terms of string, not integer. So for example, a(1) is 1 -> a(2) = 211, a(3) = 3211211 and so on. if the length of a(n) < k then return -1

Based on the problem, I tried to do it based on the length of a(n) which I thought was 2^n-1, but I quickly found out that it only works for n<10. Then I tried to calculate the gap between the pairs of same numbers, but I don't think I can. Loop is not possible here since n can be up to 10^5 (this is also a problem on its own because when I tried large numbers in c++ it showed inf, not a number to calculate). Now I'm out of ideas.

Edit: Here's an example of the problem:
Input: 5 4
so n=5 -> the number is 5432112113211211432112113211211, and the 4th digit is 2 so the output is 2

```
#include<fstream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream fi;
    fi.open("input.inp");
    double n,k;
    fi >> n >> k;
    long long l = pow(2, n)-1;
    int ans;
    if (k>l) {
        ans = -1;
    }
    else if (k==1) {
        ans = n;
    }
    else {
        k = l+1-k;
        while (n>0) {
            if (log2(k+1)==floor(log2(k+1))) {
                ans = log2(k+1);
                break;
            }
            else {
                n-=1;
                if (k-(pow(2,n)-1)>=0) {
                    k-=(pow(2,n)-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ofstream fo;
    fo.open("output.out");
    fo << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hint: the string for n = X can be divided into 3 parts, the first being X and the other 2 parts are identical, and they both start with X-1

Comment: Whenever playing with numeric digits, convert the number to a string.  The value of a digit is `unsigned int digit_value = number_as_string[x] - '0';`

Comment: Don't use `pow()` with integers.  The `pow()` function is floating point and you may encounter inaccuracies do to integer to floating point conversions.

Comment: Hint:  `pow(2, x)` is better written as `(1 << x)`.  Many processors can implement the shift in one or two instructions and doesn't require data type changes.

Comment: Everything on this site is about [tag:computer-science] one way or another. This question is not a significant enough exception to warrant the tag.

Comment: never use `log2(k+1)==floor(log2(k+1))` just like you should never use `pow(2, n)`. It's is a terrible way to [check if a variable is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/108318/995714). It's very slow and prone to error due to floating-point operations. Simply `(k + 1) & k == 0` is enough. [In C++20 there's a better solution: `std::has_single_bit`. There are also `std::countr_zero` and `std::bit_width` to replace the slow `log2(double)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit)

Answer (score 1):

First, some observations:

1. The string size is exponential in n so a(n) takes 10000 bits. The largest number type in C++ is uint64_t with 64 bits.
2. Luckily, the restriction on k means we only have to consider the first 10^15 digits, which is 35 bits and thus fits in a uint64_t.
3. a(49) is the last digit string whose size is below 10^15.

Next, the trivial case: if k <= d(n), where d(n) counts digits of the number n we can just read off the answer.

Then, for n > 50 we can safely assume the wanted digit  must reside in the first branch of a(n-1) as a(50) and up no longer fit in 10^^15. We must take care to not index into the *n* prefix, so:

```
solution(k, n) | n > 50 = solution(k - d(n), n-1)
```

Once n <= 50, k might also reach the *second* branch of a(n-1). Thus:

```
solution(k, n) | n <= 50 && k - d(n) <= a(n-1) = solution(k - d(n), n-1)
               | otherwise                     = solution(k - a(n-1) - d(n), n-1)
```

All that remains to make this efficient is to precalculate a(n) up to 50.
Implementing this in C++ is left as an exercise for the reader.

EDIT: The split at n>50 is entirely to fit the limits of a uint64_t number. If you have arbitrary-precision numbers to your disposal (eg libgmp or built-in to the language like Python or Haskell) this is just a special case of the last clause.

Comment: you might want to unroll the recursion when n > 49, or you might stack overflow, k is up to 1e15, if k is reduced by 5 per function call, you will need 2e14 calls .... a computer doesn't have that much of RAM ....

Comment: The algorithm specification is naturally recursive. Implementing it iteratively so it doesn't blow past the stack limit is part of the "exercise for the reader" :) edit: every recursion step decreases n by 1, and that is 1e5 max. that might _just_ fit in a common 8MB stack limit.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Clang and GCC turned my simple tail-recursive function into a loop, so it's not even _that_ much of an exercise for the reader ;)